# How to disable other fields when a selction is made from dropdown in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

I am working with Contact form 7 and want to disable some fields when an option is selected

I tried using some javascript code to solve it but its not workng!

```
<div class="booking-form">
<h3>BOOKING - ENJOY!</h3>
<p class="book-cf1">[text* first-name placeholder "First Name*"]</p>
<p class="book-cf1">[text* last-name placeholder "Last Name*"]</p>
<p class="book-cf1">[text* your-phone placeholder "Your Phone"]</p>
<p class="book-cf1">[email* your-email placeholder "Email Address*"]</p>
<p class="book-cf1">[text* arrival-date class:date_booking placeholder "Arrival Date*"]</p>
<p class="book-cf1">[text* departure-date class:date_booking placeholder "Departure Date*"]</p>
<p class="book-cf2">[select room_type  placeholder "Suite type" "Junior Suite" "Executive Suite" "Family Suite" "Full Service Package"]</p>
<p class="book-cf2">[select adult "Adults" "1" "2" "3" "4"]</p>
<p class="book-cf2">[select Child "Child" "1" "2" "3" "4"]</p>
<p class="book-cf2">[select etbed "Extra Bed" "1" "2"]</p>
<p class="book-cf2">[select pickup "Pickup" "Yes (+$30)" "No"]</p>
<p class="book-cf3">[textarea your-message placeholder "Special Note"]</p>
<p class="clearfix">[checkbox checkbox-838 "Please confirm your details before submitting."]</p>
<p class="book-cf3" id="book-cf4">[submit "Make a reservation"]</p>
</div
```

I expect this to happen, when i select suite type "Junior Suite", and further goes to select extra bed, only one option should show up and the other option 2 should be disabled,  but for Executive and Family Suite the two options for extra beds should be enabled, and also another one is when i  select Full Service Package, the fields  "adults,child, extra bed and pickup" should be disabled.I tried using the javascript code but not getting anywhere!